# Video iFrames not displaying on Vercel

Tags: html, iframe, vercel, youtube-iframe-api

I have a raw HTML project, deployed to Vercel with a few videos embedded in one of the pages.

Nothing fancy just:

```
<div class="size_fixed grpelem" id="u3332">
     
<iframe 
class="actAsDiv" 
width="513" 
height="320" 
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/QAKJUnOnKckautoplay=0&amp;loop=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;theme=dark&amp;color=red&amp;controls=1&amp;modestbranding=0&amp;start=0&amp;fs=1&amp;iv_load_policy=1&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;rel=1" 
frameborder="0" 
allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>
```

This works locally or when just opening the raw html file

However, when actually deployed on most browsers this is what actually renders:

```
<div class="size_fixed grpelem" id="u3332">
     
<iframe 
class="actAsDiv" 
width="513" 
height="320" 
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/QAKJUnOnKckautoplay=0&amp;loop=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;theme=dark&amp;color=red&amp;controls=1&amp;modestbranding=0&amp;start=0&amp;fs=1&amp;iv_load_policy=1&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;rel=1" 
frameborder="0" 
allowfullscreen>
 #document
   <html>
     <head></head>
     <body></body>
   </html>
</iframe>
 </div>
```

So the iFrame is rendering but the content coming back from YouTube is an empty HTML page. I have another video on Vimeo, same issue. I can replicate the issue on other browsers and other users experince the same issue.

I'm not sure if this is a Vercel thing, or Code or Youtube. Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check closely your `src` value - the `video_id` and the additional parameters are not separated.

In this part:

```
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/QAKJUnOnKckautoplay=0&amp;loop=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;theme=dark&amp;[...]"
```

You missed the **`?`** character.

Set your `src` value to:

```
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/QAKJUnOnKck?autoplay=0&amp;loop=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;theme=dark&amp;[...]"
```